# Finding vertical datum for bathymetry layer?

Tags: datum, bathymetry

I was given a layer that shows bathymetry, and I need to list the vertical datum for the it on the map.

Is this somewhere in the layer properties?

I only see datum. I don't know the source for the bathymetry layer.

How can I find the vertical datum?

Comment: Raster or vector data?  Is there a Z value listed in the attribute table?

Answer (score 3):

The datum will only be specified if the creator of the dataset put it in there. If you're given a dataset and it's missing the coordinate system, datum, or both (horizontal or vertical), you'll need to track down its origin (a parent dataset, the person who gave it to you, etc.) to find it.

If that proves impossible, you may be able to make an educated guess by comparing your bathymetry values to other data sources which cover the same area and do have a known datum, like navigation charts.